# Match using regular expression

Tags: android, regex, android-edittext

(I want a vehicle number validation in edit text android)

my string sample is like this:gj05rs1234

FIrst (gj) char are characters.
Second (05) are numbers.
Third (rs)are chars
Fourth(1234) are numbers

And I want regex in java ...
Please help me to generate regex for this expression

Comment: Or you could try to learn about Regex, try it yourself and come back with the issues you face, if any, we are not here to code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
System.out.println(string.matches("[a-z]{2}\\d{2}[a-z]{2}\\d{4}"));
```

Comment: I am using this pattern for matching  str_regexPattern ="[a-z]{2}\\s+\\d{1,2}\\s+[a-z]{1,2}\\s+\\d{3,4}$"; but I need only 4 digits at end and its accepting more than four numbers also ..please correct me

Comment: use matches method. If you want to use pattern and matcher class then you need to add anchors like `"^[a-z]{2}\\d{2}[a-z]{2}\\d{4}$"`

Comment: you dont need to use `\\s` which matches a space character.

Comment: applied this for zero or more spaces but not working for end stringstr_tempPattern="[a-z]{2}\\X*\\d{1,2}\\X*[a-z]\\X*\\d{1,4}$"

Comment: it's not `\\X*`, it's `\\s*` to match zero or more spaces.

Comment: I have done it for indian vehicle number regex String str_tempPattern="^[A-Z]{2}\\s*[0-9]{1,2}\\s*(?: [A-Z])?(?: \\s*[A-Z]*)?\\s* [0-9]{1,4}$";

Comment: why you make the in-between `[A-Z]` as optional? Please ask this as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

i think you could follow this link to format regex

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/string/java-string-format-example/